# compile error: "Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'Platforms/CCGL.h' file not found"

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have already viewed following solutions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999969/static-library-path-nightmare-from-hell) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925539/lexical-or-preprocessor-issue-file-not-found-occurs-while-archiving).

I've been at it for hours now & this is why i finally came here to ask. It started off with a warning:

```
Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'int.'
```

Then Xcode prompted me to make updates, and all i did was press Enter to accept it. After that, running the application on my device leaves me with the error i put in the question title above.

Thank you in advance for helping.

Update: No luck. 24 hours later, I restored the project to when the Build updates were prompted and I did not accept it. Still, running the app gives a 'Lexical or Preprocessor Issue,' only now it cannot find the file 'Support/ccCArray.h' and there are Semantic Issues on the line `static const ccBlendFunc kCCBlendFuncDisable = {GL_ONE, GL_ZERO};` If anybody has any advice or is working on it, I really appreciate it, this is so frustrating. It's two days in now, and I just can't find a solution. I don't know what to even try anymore.

More info: I am using Cocos2d-iPhone v2.1. The original implicit conversion error is on the line `highScore = [defaults integerForKey:@"theHighScore"];`

Comment: Post the code where the original error appears. Also mention which version of cocos2d you are using (see log or cocos2d.m file)

Comment: Those details are now posted at the end of my question, by "More info." @LearnCocos2D